# Java aliquant number

Tags: java, double

I am practicing a question: Type several numbers and stops while you type 0. Print out the maximum, minimum and average of the numbers you type.

Following is my code, and I was stuck in the calculation of average.
For example: when I type: 2 5 7 -1 0
the outcome is :

```
Type some numbers, and type 0 to end the calculattion: 
2 5 7 -1 0
The numbers you type are: 
2 5 7 -1 
Sum is: 13
There are 4 numbers
The Max number is : 7
The minimum number is : -1
Average is : 3.0
```

However, the Average should be 3.25.
I've already made the variable avg in double type, why my output is still 3.0 rather than 3.25?

Thanks!!

```
public class Max_Min_Avg {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Type some numbers, and type 0 to end the calculattion: ");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numbs = scanner.nextInt();
    int count =0;
    int sum =0;
    int max = 0;
    int min=0;
    System.out.println("The numbers you type are: ");
    while(numbs!=0) {
        System.out.print(numbs + " ");
        sum += numbs;
        count ++;
        numbs = scanner.nextInt();
        if(numbs>max) {
            max = numbs;
        }
        if(numbs<min) {
            min = numbs;
        }
    }
    while(numbs ==0) {
        break;

    }

    System.out.println();
    double avg = (sum/count);
    System.out.println("Sum is: "+ sum);
    System.out.println("There are "+ count + " numbers");
    System.out.println("The Max number is : " + max );
    System.out.println("The minimum number is : " + min);
    System.out.println("Average is : " + avg);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the issue of integer division .`sum/count` is calculated as int since `sum` and `count` is of type `int`. You can solve this by  **implicit casting**.

Try :-

```
double avg = sum*1.0/count;   // implicit casting.
```

Output :-

```
Type some numbers, and type 0 to end the calculattion: 
2 5 7 -1 0
The numbers you type are: 
2 5 7 -1 
Sum is: 13
There are 4 numbers
The Max number is : 7
The minimum number is : -1
Average is : 3.25
```